# How to get the data type of table of csv or text file that is exported from sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

How to get the data type details of the table that is exported from SQL Server as txt or csv file on bulk export ?

Can any one please suggest me on this...

Thanks,
Harl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Format File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190393.aspx):

> When you bulk import data into a SQL Server table or bulk export data from a table, you can use a format file to store all the format information that is required to bulk export or bulk import data. This includes format information for each field in a data file relative to that table.

Comment: Hi Remus Rusanu, thank you for ur suggestion. Will try it with format file btwn if hav ny reference link plz share... Thanx... :)